# jQuery toggle .click() function

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle, jquery-events

I am unsure if this is a "callback' that I need or not, but basically I am trying to emulate the reversal of the function like on the .hover() effect with the .click() effect. Is this possible. So basically, if the user clicks again on the link, the reverse of what just happened, ie a div closing as opposed to opening, will happen. Is it possible to do this with .click()?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.content_accrd').css({"height":"0px"});
$('.paneltop').click( function() {
    $(this).css({"background-position":"0px -21px"})
    .siblings().animate({"height":"100px"}, 200)
}, function() {
$(this).css({"background-position":"0px 0px"})
    .siblings().animate({"height":"0px"}, 200);

})
})
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`.toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/), not `.click()`.

> ***Description:*** Bind two or more handlers to the matched elements, to be executed on alternate clicks.

Comment: Also, is that technically what I wanted? a callback? or is it called something else?

Comment: I don't think "callback" is the term for what you wanted. A callback (in JavaScript, anyway) is a function to be executed at a later time. The 3 anonymous functions in your code are all examples of callbacks. The first one is a callback which is executed when the DOM is ready.

Comment: A brief write-up on JS callbacks: http://recurial.com/programming/understanding-callback-functions-in-javascript/ (the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callback_%28computer_programming%29) might be a bit opaque...)

Comment: .toggle() is deprecated since v.1.8 - Use conditionals instead (if..else..)

Answer (score 2):

try toggle

```
$(".paneltop").toggle(function(){
    //first click happened
},function(){
    //second click happened
});
```

Comment: Can someone explain his/her downvote so I can improve my answer?

Comment: That would be my downvote - sorry, I was going to comment but got sidetracked. I downvoted your original answer, because it was just plain wrong. Why didn't you just edit it? Anyway, it amounted to the same information as my answer, after I'd already posted (and downvoted your wrong answer).

Comment: @MattBall: I have deleted it because it was downvoted long time before and chances to get upvoted is very small.

Comment: There were 2 downvotes. One of them was mine. I am happy to remove downvotes when an answer is fixed. I imagine that your other downvoter would do the same.

Comment: @MattBall: Okay. So what's the reason for still keeping your downvote on my post now, though?

Answer (score 0):

No, the click action will always do the same thing. If you want it to have alternating effects you will have to check the current state of the element and switch it to the new state accordingly.

This looks something like:

```
  $('#foo').click(function () {
    if ( $('#foo').is(':visible') ) {
      $('#foo').hide();
    } else {
      $('#foo').show();
    }
  });
```

Depending on the effect you are trying to achieve this could be any change you want.

Comment: 1. Where do you see an element with ID `foo`? 2. Why would you ever use this instead of [`.toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)? -1.

Comment: 1. Just a demo that could be applied to any element(s). 2. Yes, reading the OP's question they specifically ask for an ability to reverse the action (similar to mouseover effects). This may not necessarily be a show/hide toggle but any kind of switch. And could be caused by multiple triggering elements we need to keep track of the current state of the element.

Comment: Toggle will not work if there is more than one element on the page that can cause the state change. The only way to be sure is to query the current state and switch to the opposite state. Sorry that you feel this is incorrect and worth a downvote. But everyone is entitled to their opinion.